# To find out Longest substring which repeated 2 or more time

Tags: algorithm

I JUST  wanted to write logic to check longest substring of a given string which is repeated 2 or more than 2 times

ex - 
          string str =  aabbcaaaaaaaabbcaaabbccaabddaab

```
      To find out Longest substring which repeated 2 or more times.

      output:  aabbcaa
```

Comment: You wanted to, but did you try to?

Answer (score 2):

In order to do this efficiently you should look into tries.

Here's a link to a [tutorial on using tries](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=usingTries). In particular a prefix tree.

Comment: Now see what happened with our little discussion. Hope you understand better now :( http://stackoverflow.com/q/15210825/353410

Comment: @belisarius, yes I saw that.. I'll know better in the future

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple (but inefficient) algorithm: Loop all possible substring lengths, from the maximum down to 1. For each length, put all substrings of that length into a dictionary. If you find a duplicate, stop. It must be the largest one. Here is the corresponding C# code:

```
public static string FindDuplicateSubstring(string s)
    {
        for (int len = s.Length-1; len > 0; len--) {
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            for (int i = 0; i <= s.Length - len; i++) {
                string sub = s.Substring(i, len);
                if (dict.ContainsKey(sub)) return sub;
                else dict[sub] = i;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

For example, when applied to the text of your question, the longest repeated substring is "implementation". Note that overlapping substrings are allowed, i.e. the input "bbbb" returns "bbb". It wasn't clear from your question if you wanted to exclude the overlapping case. For a faster approach, see my other answer.

or

[good example. here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Programming_Languages/C_Sharp/Q_21083206.html)

I have to sort the ArrayList first and then i have compare ontacts[ i ] with contacts[ i-1 ]

```
contacts.Sort();


for (int i=1; i <= contacts.Count-1; i++)
{
Console.WriteLine(contacts[ i ]);
Console.WriteLine(contacts[ i-1] );
if(contacts[ i ].ToString() == contacts[ i-1 ].ToString())
{
Console.WriteLine("Duplicate: "+contacts[ i ]);
}
}
```